# Insert data into database with a method of a class

Tags: database, insert, abap

I am trying to create a method to insert data to the database but it does not work. I am trying to insert data by using `add_person`. Here is my code. The transparent table name is `ZPERSON_20`.

```
CLASS lcl_person DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      add_person
        IMPORTING 
          im_id   TYPE zperson_20-person_id
          im_name TYPE zperson_20-person_name
          im_add  TYPE zperson_20-person_address
          im_type TYPE zperson_20-person_type.

  PRIVATE SECTION.
    DATA:
     c_id   TYPE zperson_20-person_id,
     c_name TYPE zperson_20-person_name,
     c_add  TYPE zperson_20-person_address,
     c_type TYPE zperson_20-person_type.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_person IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD add_person.
    DATA: it_emp TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zperson_20.
    DATA: wa_emp LIKE LINE OF it_emp.

    wa_emp-person_id   = c_id.
    wa_emp-person_name = c_name.
    wa_emp-person_add  = c_add.
    wa_emp-person_type = c_type.

    INSERT INTO zperson_20 VALUES wa_emp.
  ENDMETHOD.                
ENDCLASS.

PARAMETERS:
  v_id   TYPE zperson_20-person_id,
  v_name TYPE zperson_20-person_name,
  v_add  TYPE zperson_20-person_address,
  v_type TYPE zperson_20-person_type.

DATA: lv_ref_person TYPE REF TO lcl_person.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  CREATE OBJECT lv_ref_person.
  CALL METHOD lv_ref_person->add_person(
    im_id   = v_id
    im_name = v_name
    im_add  = v_add
    im_type = v_type
  ).
```

Comment: what error message did you get?

Comment: Field "IM_ID" is unkown.It is neither in one of the specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.

Comment: I think you should run a syntax check on your class. I can't get it to compile in my system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert data into table by using class method(abap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891567/insert-data-into-table-by-using-class-methodabap)

Answer (score 1):

I would say your issue is inside the add_person method, as you are reading the values from the member variables, instead of the method parameters. Those member variables will probably be empty in this case, leading to inserting errors due to an empty or duplicated id.

I believe that the code you are trying to achieve is the following:

```
REPORT ZRKD_BASE_WSLOADER.

CLASS lcl_person DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      add_person
        IMPORTING
          im_id   TYPE zperson_20-person_id
          im_name TYPE zperson_20-person_name
          im_add  TYPE zperson_20-person_address
          im_type TYPE zperson_20-person_type.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_person IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD add_person.    
    DATA: wa_emp TYPE zperson_20.

    //---->  Here are the modifications <-------

    wa_emp-person_id   = im_id.
    wa_emp-person_name = im_name.
    wa_emp-person_address  = im_add.
    wa_emp-person_type = im_type.

    INSERT INTO zperson_20 VALUES wa_emp.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

PARAMETERS:
  v_id   TYPE zperson_20-person_id,
  v_name TYPE zperson_20-person_name,
  v_add  TYPE zperson_20-person_address,
  v_type TYPE zperson_20-person_type.

DATA: lv_ref_person TYPE REF TO lcl_person.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  CREATE OBJECT lv_ref_person.
  CALL METHOD lv_ref_person->add_person(
    im_id   = v_id
    im_name = v_name
    im_add  = v_add
    im_type = v_type
  ).
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be enough to create a commit method, which you then call, if You are really sure to save on  db, or add this parameter as a flag to add person. If set, commit the transaction. The instruction for this  is "commit work." and it is missing in the entire snippet. And without it nothing moves from  Your actual LUW commit buffer  to db.

Answer (score 0):

Your method add_person is defined to take no arguments and you are passing it arguments. Basically there is a disagreement in call and the definition.

Can you post the whole code here?

Comment: Did not look at compiling issues. I admit. But commit is missing at all.